# Convert a series to numbers into another series of fixed size

Tags: sequences-and-series

Given a series of 30 random numbers in the ascending order - 120, 140, 220, 250, 400, 422, 451, 800, 864 etc.,

How can I resize each number to another one so that the sum of final list is exactly 1000. The resized number should be a whole number. The size of each resized number should be relative to its original value. For eg. If 120 is resized to 100 then 140 should be resized to 117.

The resize ratio need not be 100% same for all the numbers. And the final number in the list can be floored/ceiled to fit the max. limit of 1000.

Comment: If each new number must be an integer, I don't think you will be guaranteed each number can be resized by the same ratio.

Comment: @turkeyhundt The resize need not be 100% accurate. The last number in the series can be adjusted to fit the maximum limit of 1000.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can fudge a little to make them all whole numbers, just multiply each number by $\frac{1000}{\text{sum of all numbers}}$

Then use a floor or ceiling or rounding function to make them into whole numbers.

Adding a **Ruby** implementation:

```
> a = [120, 140, 220, 250, 400, 422, 451, 800, 864]
> a.map {|b| (b * (1000.0/a.sum)).round }
=> [33, 38, 60, 68, 109, 115, 123, 218, 236]
> a.map {|b| (b * (1000.0/a.sum)).round }.sum
=> 1000
```